Migration of customizations to XM Cloud
In our Sitecore 9.3 application we did customizations in commands, pipelines, ribbons. Considering automatic upgrade of XM Cloud - SaaS product, will these customizations be overwritten during upgrades? If yes, can you please guide how to handle these customizations post migration to XM Cloud?

CM Level customization can’t be migrated or applied. If any output related customization then handle at Front end app or have API layer which will change the output and return to Front end app. You can check https://enlightenwithamit.hashnode.dev/tech-bites for some useful information

Thanks Amit....

@Sumit "summed" it up nicely, just to clarify a few things:

You can't "Upgrade" from XP/XM to XM Cloud, as Sumit mentioned, they are not the same product. Moving from XM/XP (any version) is always a migration effort. There are a lot of similarities so in some cases you can get some code reuse and some content reuse (if you are on MVC SXA in XM or XP). But be clear - it is not an upgrade and you will not be using the same code repository for your XM Cloud project.
XM Cloud is a SaaS product, while at the time of writing you can deploy customizations to the platform, these customizations should be reserved for situations where there is 100% not another way to achieve the same goal. In some situations you may need to deploy a config patch file where the setting has not been moved to an environment variable yet.
For your customizations, you will need to take them on a case by case basis and identify what the business requirement for each customization was and how that requirement can be met in the SaaS application. There are different ways of achieving the same goal when you are in SaaS/Headless vs MVC.


XM Cloud and XP/XM are two different products from Sitecore. While XP/XM is meant to be extensible and easily configurable as needed, XM Cloud is a Headless SaaS Product and doesn't offer the same flexibility. So it is highly recommended that minimum or no customizations be done as Sitecore constantly improves the environment with new changes.
When performing the migration, you need to exclude all the customizations you had in your XP/XM instance and migrate only the content. You can use the XM to XM Cloud Content Migration Tool: https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/xm-cloud
